# Nativescript custom gradle task

Tags: nativescript

How to run a custom gradle task in a nativescript android project?

Use case:

I want to upload the apk to google app store using the plugin bellow:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'

play {
    serviceAccountEmail = 'bla@user.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    pk12File = file('../../key.p12')
    track = 'alpha'
}
```

The plugin creates *publishApkRelease* task

How to run that task alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the snippet in the gradle script located in your `platforms/android/build.gradle` and then use the gradle wrapper to invoke the task like so `./gradlew publishApkRelease` for bash or `gradlew publishApkRelease` in the Windows CMD.

Note that if you delete the platforms/android dir, or modify it by removing/re-adding platform through the `tns` CLI the changes in the gradle script will be wiped. Make a local copy of the build script or write a hook that will modify the gradle file if you don't want to lose your changes.

Comment: Sad news is that build.gradle is overrided. But it works for now, thanks